# Ability to isolate and export answers?

Tags: feature-request, offline, printing, export

I've just seen [an answer to a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4986673/c11-rvalues-and-move-semantics-confusion/4986802#4986802) that is so useful for me I'd like to clip it out and save it for later. What would be really great would be some kind of link that would isolate the answer (with, optionally, the question) so I could save it to a PDF for offline viewing and reference.

Would such a feature be of value to anyone else?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have a script that can be used for this purpose..

["Print this post"](https://stackapps.com/questions/3307/print-this-post)

Install it, use the "print" link and then use the in-built browser print-to-pdf. Links will be preserved

You can still bug the SE devs to make it a feature :)

Alternatively, make the question a favorite--it'll be listed in your profile.

Comment: That is _exactly_ what I was looking for -- it'd be great to see it implemented natively, too, but nice job!

Comment: @fbrereto - quite a few things that started as user scripts have been "adopted" and polished officially.